# What causes lag in Minecraft on Hypixel Skyblock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

My son keeps having lag issues playing Minecraft on Hypixel SkyBlock. Sometimes his FPS goes down to like 3 FPS, but other times it's completely acceptable, like up around 20-30 FPS.

He claims if he had a faster computer, it would eliminate the lag, but my theory is that the cause of lag is not a lack of computer power, but the load on the server.

The computer is an ASUS chromebox3 (with 8 GB, Intel Celeron 3865U) running Minecraft Linux version in Crostini.

What is the likely cause of this lag? Is there a way for me to track down the cause by checking the load on Hypixel?

Comment: Sorry, but I think your Son is in fact correct. That computer is relatively weak for any kind of gaming workload. Seeing that it runs Chrome OS (or at least probably did before you installed Linux?), most "Chromebooks" don't pack much of a punch because they aren't really intended to be used for gaming, but rather productivity. Minecraft is a *CPU* intensive game. And Celeron processor's aren't exactly known for their performance.

Comment: Then why would the FPS drop from an acceptable 20 FPS to completely unacceptable 3 FPS?   I'm wondering if the sudden drop (after 2 hours of play) from 20 to 3 FPS would be due to a server load, network issue, or local computer resources, and local computer resources seems to be the only controllable variable

Comment: Most people wouldn't find 20FPS acceptable if I'm honest. Have you tried to play in a single player offline world? What happens then?

Comment: The huge lag only happens when he's playing on Hypixel.   So I'm wondering if there's a status page at Hypixel where I can see up-to-the-second statistics on server load that might play a role ....or does server load on Hypixel never affect the connected clients to that degree?

Comment: @TimmyJim: Just to clarify, Minecraft uses both CPU and GPU to a significant degree. I'm guessing this Chromebox has an integrated GPU and is struggling to display the larger number of cube faces you get from the floating islands that are typical of SkyBlock (but only when the user is looking in certain directions, so that many exposed block faces are within the viewing frustum). The CPU is probably also a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to buy a new device, your best bet would just be to lower the display settings to the lowest possible option. The device you mentioned is not a very powerful one, and minecraft is a very unoptimized and laggy game. You could also try installing [Optifine](https://optifine.net) which is a lag optimizing mod. The load on the Hypixel servers wouldn't affect your experience because it's running on their servers, not your laptop.